# Allow only certain files in Apache

Tags: server, apache2, django

The application I built with the django runs on the linux server. As a result of one process I have done in this app, the file.txt is created in this directory: **/home/user/app/media/file.txt**

My goal is to access this created file from my own machine where the program is running.(I use the app at macOsx). When I typed **IP:/home/user/app/media/file.txt** on browser, I cannot access texts in file. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Note: I inserted below code to conf. file in **/etc/apache2/.conf** but no hope.

```
<Directory /home/user/app/media>
   <Files file.txt>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
 </Directory>
```

Comment: If the directory is already set as `/home/user/app/media`, then you do not need to put this in your URL. You can use `{IP}/file.txt`. However, depending on which OS you're using, there may be some additional settings you need to configure in order to allow Apache to read from `/home`. By default, Apache is limited to `/var/www`.

Comment: You were right! It works exactly like that {IP}/media/file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are providing looks a bit strange with the ":" after "IP". Furthermore, you should setup a virtual host using you own URL (e.g. "myapp.local") and put this in the /etc/hosts file (`127.0.0.1 myapp.local`).

Please find the config for an apache ***virtual host*** below. place it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf` and activate using `sudo a2ensite myapp.conf`.

Please note the `ServerName`: this is the URL you should type in the browser.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# This config will serve the built version of the production version of the crisisgame.molema.org website for local use with local parameters
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myapp.local

    DocumentRoot /home/user/app
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    
    <Directory /home/user/app/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.myapp.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.myapp.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Then edit you `/etc/hosts` and add:

```
  127.0.0.1 myapp.local
```

Then restart the Apache2 Service using `sudo service apache2 restart`.

If restarting the service yields an error, then follow the procedure below to find the error. This will elevate you to root-privileged new shell, set Apache's environment variables and then ask Apache to run a check (-S parameter)

```bash
 martin@debian:~$ sudo -i
 [Password]: 
 root@debian:~# cd /etc/apache2
 root@debian:~# . ./envvars
 root@debian:~# apache2 -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
```

Notice the way `envvars` is executed: dot-space-dot-slash prefixed. This means that if the script `envvars`  modifies environment variables their values will be available in the current shell (the first `.` represents the current shell). See also [Bash Reference Manual, chapter 3.7.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment).

The first error usually is no problem. If this report shows other errors, go fix them. Possibly lookup the configs for Apache2 [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)

Go to your browser and type `http://myapp.local/media/file.txt`.

Good luck!

Greetings Martin